Error in setup.py (cx_freeze) while converting a tkinter application to an exe file
Can somebody please tell me why i am getting error while running python setup.py build command?
setup.py
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {
    "packages": ["customtkinter",
                 "tkinter",
                 "PIL",
                 "tkcalendar",
                 "os",
                 "sqlite3",
                 "random",
                 "string",
                 "datetime",
                 "qrcode",
                 "pyzbar",
                 "cv2",
                 "numpy",
                 "matplotlib",
                 "pandas",
                 "requests",
                 "calendar",
                 ],  # Add any additional packages your script depends on
    "include_files": [
        ("employee_qrcodes", "employee_qrcodes"),
        ("frame_2_icons", "frame_2_icons"),
        ("frame_3_icons", "frame_3_icons"),
        ("frame_4_icons", "frame_4_icons"),
        ("frame_5_icons", "frame_5_icons"),
        ("frame_6_icons", "frame_6_icons"),
        ("frame_7_icons", "frame_7_icons"),
        ("member_qrcodes", "member_qrcodes"),
        ("test_images", "test_images"),
        ("trainer_qrcodes", "trainer_qrcodes"),
        # Add more include_files as needed
        ("venv", "venv"),
        ("attendance_records.db", "attendance_records.db"),
        ("employee_attendance_records.db", "employee_attendance_records.db"),
        ("pat.png", "pat.png"),
        ("README.md", "README.md"),
        ("register_employee.db", "register_employee.db"),
        ("register_equipment.db", "register_equipment.db"),
        ("register_trainer.db", "register_trainer.db"),
        ("registered_users.db", "registered_users.db"),
        ("registration_form.db", "registration_form.db"),
        ("requirements.txt", "requirements.txt"),
        ("trainer_attendance_records.db", "trainer_attendance_records.db"),
        ("visitors_log.db", "visitors_log.db"),
    ],
}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"  # Use this option if you want to hide the console window

executables = [Executable("gym.py", base=base)]

setup(
    name="GymApplication",
    version="0.1",
    description="Your Gym Application Description",
    options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables=executables,
)

(.venv) PS C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\gyms\gyms> python setup.py build
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\gyms\gyms\setup.py", line 2, in 
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\gyms.venv\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze_init_.py", line 11, in 
from .command.build_exe import BuildEXE as build_exe
File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\gyms.venv\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\command\build_exe.py", line 14, in 
from cx_Freeze.freezer import Freezer
File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\gyms.venv\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 31, in 
from .finder import ModuleFinder
File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\gyms.venv\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 33, in 
IMPORT_STAR = opcode.opmap["IMPORT_STAR"]
~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'IMPORT_STAR'

I'd really appreciate if someone can tell me why

Wait, i think i fixed the problem! You just have to install the pre-released version of cx_freeze, (pip install cx-Freeze==7.0.0rc0) and then run "python setup.py build". and the app will be converted to executable. and now it works well

Ther is an issue in the package of cx_Freeze that's why it is corrupted.
Run:- pip install --upgrade cx_Freeze
then ensure that the dependencies are installed properly of cx_Freeze
and
python setup.py clean
python setup.py build
run these :-)

The problem is i kept encountering the same error even if i upgraded the cx_freeze

Damn what's wrong with cx_freeze. last december i just converted my tkinter app into exe using the setup.py and it works well. But this time i can't

Wait, i think i fixed the problem! You just have to install the pre-released version of cx_freeze, (pip install cx-Freeze==7.0.0rc0) and then run "python setup.py build". and the app will be converted to executable. and now it works well
